# wkhtmltopdf header-html displays blank area, even with doctype

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf version 0.12.2.1 and am attempting to add a header to each page that contains two images. I have tried both using img tags and `background-image` styling on a div, neither of which works. I also tried adding some plain text, and that does not show up either. What I do see is a white opaque stripe that overlays at the top of the page, cutting off any content I have near the top. Strangely, I have tried changing the height value of the top-level div, and as I increase the value, the resulting height of the white strip actually decreases. Any idea what could be causing this, and how I would be able to fix it?

Here are the contents of the header HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .rm-pdf-header {
        height: 60px;
        width: 100%;
        background-image: url(/img/banner1.png);
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        color: #fff;
        position: relative;
    }
    .rm-pdf-header-arrow {
        position: absolute;
        background-image: url(/img/image2.png);
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 90px;
        height: 90px;
        top: 26px;
        right: 26px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="rm-pdf-header">
        <div class="rm-pdf-header-arrow"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the header file in the PDF options section. Read the Headers and Footers section of: https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, I'd suggest you quote the important parts of the linked resource, this would make your answer much better. You can read more about referencing material written by others [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)